# How to execute a function when the device's physical back button is pressed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to handle the android device's physical back button, what I mean is that I'm not using an AppBar in the application so there's no back button the only back button there is the device physical back button and I want to handle the click on it.

this is the button I'm talking about

[image]

how can I do that??

Comment: This really depends on what you want to do with the interception of the tap on the button. But actually overriding the behaviour of the physical back button is not possible. It would also defy the proper user experience of an Android device. It's called the back button and users expect it to do exactly that go back. If you want to avoid the app or view to close, that can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WillPopScope widget to do so.

following code may help you more.

```
WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
```

Comment: how should i use it, in a function or what?

Comment: you have to wrap your scaffold as i shown in demo code.

Answer (score 0):

But what if, I want to perform another function or call my function when this back button is pressed.

I am not able to call it there in **WillPopScope** because it only takes boolean value.

For Example :

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
  },
```

I am getting this kind of error

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr', is a potentially non-nullable type.